# Alter table error MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES(
EmployeeNumber INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
LastName Char(35)  NOT NULL,
FirstName CHAR(35)  NOT NULL,
Department CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeNumber));

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
DepartmentName CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
Phone CHAR(35)  NOT NULL,
BudgetCode  CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  DEP_PK  PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentName));
```

I forgot make a department as foreign key in employees, so i did

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES ADD CONSTRAINT EMP_DEP_FK
  FOREIGN KEY(Department) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName)
```

and this showed me:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "EMP_DEP_FK". The conflict occurred in database "WPC", table
>   "dbo.DEPARTMENT", column 'DepartmentName'.

Comment: That generally means you have some data in the child table that is not in the parent table. You need to look for that and fix it.

Comment: This runs fine on SQL Server once you fix your spelling errors and missing comma.

Comment: Or I notice that the spelling of DepartmentName is incorrect in your table structure so it doesn't match what is in the FK. If that is really true in your actual table, then fix that.

Comment: I would also personally be wary of using something like Department Name as a PK. It is entirely possible for two different departments in two different parts of a large organization to have teh same name so there is no guarantee of uniqueness..

Comment: It example, so it not main idea :D and departmentnname is incrrect just here, is mistake only here. In mysql i worte without mistake

Comment: and char(35) is astrange datatype to store names in it. shouldn't it be varchar?

Comment: Change the code in your post so that we can try to properly address the issue, especially if the code you are using is different than what you posted as you have stated, please.

Comment: @Bopinko well you need to give us the correct code. Else, we can't help you finding mistakes and errors.

Comment: CODE IS RIGTH NOW CORRECT

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your DEPARTMENT table ==> **DepartmetnName**.

Should have been DepartmentName instead.